# I would like to display the 'infopath form' with some functionality in sharepoint webpart

Tags: c#-4.0, sharepoint-2010, sharepoint-designer, infopath2010

I would like to show the infopath form  with some functionality in sharepoint webpart? Does any one know how to implement the infopathforms display in sharepoint webpart? can i get the sample code

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

you can use the InfoPath Form WebPart, see this article [here](http://www.chakkaradeep.com/post/SharePoint-2010-InfoPath-Form-Web-Part.aspx)